# Como fazer dialog com listview dentro?

Tags: android, dialog

Gostaria de saber como faço para criar um `Dialog` contendo uma `ListView` seguindo o exemplo da imagem abaixo.

[image: dialog_listview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um modo simples de fazer isso é utilizar o método setItems do Dialog, a partir dele você seta a sua lista, e ela é carregada automaticamente no Dialog.

**Exemplo:**

```
final CharSequence[] cores = {"Azul", "Preto", "Verde"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CONTEXT);
    builder.setTitle("Selecione uma Cor");
    builder.setItems(cores, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selecionado) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cor Selecionada: " + cores[selecionado],
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
```

**Obs: O context seria uma instância da sua activity, se estiver executando dentro de uma activity, pode usar this;**

Answer (score 0):

DialogFragments podem funcionar como caixas de diálogo em Android. Elas funcionam como "Activity sobre outra Activity" e, visto na sua imagem, é possivel fazer uma tela desse jeito (apresentando um Widget de ListView). Dê uma olhada em alguns exemplos: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/components/fragments.html
http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html